# Selecteditem event in MVVM silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

i have a datagrid bound to a property. In this grid i have columns which consists of cells which are like hyperlink i mean when user clicks on the cell value based on these values another gird will get populated. i want to know how to get the cell value and pass it to some method so that other grid will get populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is in your viewmodel.

You should bind the `SelectedItem` of your datagrid to a new property in your ViewModel. In the set method of this new Property, call a new method to populate a new ObservableCollection/List/whatever...

Finally, bind your "other grid" `ItemsSource` to this new observable collection from your ViewModel.

Edit:
If you need to load one thing or another depending on the column you are going to use the code behind, take a look at this:
[Silverlight DataGrid how to get cell value from a selected item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120952/silverlight-datagrid-how-to-get-cell-value-from-a-selected-item)

Comment: but the problem is i want to pass the selected cell value and its column name as a parameter.

Comment: it is bound to ObservableCollection<someclass>.

Comment: Then you have to make a SomeClass property and bind your SelectedItem to it. Then you can use the SomeClass property you want to load the new ObservableCollection.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16633/discussion-between-neo-and-zapico)

Comment: private Effort cellSelected;

        public Effort CellSelected
        {
            get { return cellSelected; }
            private set
            {
                if (cellSelected != value)
                {
                    
                    cellSelected = value;                    
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("CellSelected");
                }
            }
        }
here i have declared the property but how would i know which column and value the user selected?

Comment: That's what I mean when I say you'll have to use code behind. I can't think of anyway doing it through MVVM 8-)

Comment: Take a look at this other one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089650/silverlight-datagrid-celltemplate-binding-to-viewmodel?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. i think its only way out.